# Trying to use fewer than all the factors across columns in a t test

Tags: r

I have two different factorial experiments. Let's say that in experiment one there is a treatment column that splits all reps into treatments 1 and 2. Then there is a second treatment where columns are split again, and a third column splitting them again. There is also a code for each treatment (8, if you're following). I need to do t tests between 2 opposing treatments.

I've tried factor, mydata and subset and get error messages each time, especially since then a t test has 80 variables in the independent variable.  Here are the examples (except the factor one)

```
myvars <- c("SH1RUC", "SH1RC")
newdata <- mydata[myvars]

newdata <- subset(december, shadehouse=="1" & system=="open" & media=="coir")
```

I'd like to be able to grab either shadehouse, either system and either media for doing t tests. Otherwise I'd like to grab the name, i.e. "SH1RUC" or "SH1RC," grouped together, to run a t test.

Based on the comment, here is a sample dataset:

```
   Dep1 Dep2 Dep3 Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
1     1    3    5 4.63   65   21
2     1    3    5 5.25   64   22
3     1    3    6 4.76   67   23
4     1    3    6 5.87   65   24
5     1    4    5 4.65   87   25
6     1    4    5 5.76   67   21
7     1    4    6 3.99   75   22
8     1    4    6 4.09   46   23
9     2    3    5 5.98   68   24
10    2    3    5 3.67   79   25
11    2    3    6 5.43   75   22
12    2    3    6 4.56   57   23
13    2    4    5 5.43   65   24
14    2    4    5 2.99   68   25
15    2    4    6 4.09   58   26
16    2    4    6 5.70   56   23
```

I'm trying to perform a t test between two specific dependent variable sets, for example rows 1 & 2 and rows 9 & 10, or rows 5 & 6 and rows 7 & 8. In the actual data there are 10 data points for each set, and I want to compare the means. I can't seems to group columns together effectively.

Comment: Here's a sample

Comment: I just figured out how to use subset more effectively by selecting by rows.